# Any games like Werewolf for two persons?

Tags: one-night-werewolf, two-player

I am totaly new on board cards games. I tried WereWolf for one night last weekend, and I wonder what other games in same logic ?

If to take into account that I want a board game playable for 2 persons, it's not possible with werewolf, but any other games in same logic please ?

Comment: Werewords (Deluxe?) includes rules for two players. It's not the deepest experience, but it's nice for when you just have a few minutes.

Comment: Game recommendation questions are off topic as they tend to end up with list type answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Werewolf is not playable by two, as you say.

But if you want modern boardgames for two with a small footprint and a guessing mechanism there are many.

For example:

- The Mind
- Mr. Jack Pocket
- Saboteur: The Duel.
- Codenames Duet
- Sherlock Holmes Consulting Detective (larger footprint)

Comment: Mr. Jack the not pocket version, hits the mark too

Comment: I immediately thought of Codenames Duet

Answer (score 1):

You might like [Love Letter](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/129622/love-letter) - it has some similar mechanics, and is for 2-4 players.

Answer (score 0):

my personal best light weight 2-player game is [Battle Line](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/760/battle-line)

check BGG's list of [best 2-player games](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2008425/best-two-player-game)

or a list of [games this guy play with his wife](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/198463/my-wifes-list-mkay-and-yes-games)